# row to column and populate in grid in unanimo.i have Data In Rows And I want to convert to Column

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9iss.png)

i want to show this SDT Split Item Convert to column in grid.

i tried all ways but not show it gives error,i tried all ways to show simple SDT in grid but also simple grid is not showing,please see this